# Ordering: Normalized

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a Hilbert space $1\in\mathcal{A}$.

Denote selfadjoints:
$$\mathcal{S}:=\{A\in\mathcal{A}:A=A^*\}$$

Introduce an order:
$$A\leq A':\ \ \sigma(A'-A)\geq0$$

Regard a projection:
$$P\neq0:\quad P^2=P=P^*$$

Then one has:
$$P\leq A\leq1\implies\|A\|=1$$

How can I check this?

*(Operator-algebraic proof?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to relate the norm with the spectrum, I don't think this has an elementary algebraic proof.

Facts needed (from the theory of Banach algebras):

1. For any $A\in\mathcal S$, $\sigma(A)=\{\phi(A):\ \phi\in S(\mathcal A)\}$, where $S(\mathcal A)$ is the state space.
2. For any $A\in\mathcal S$, $\|A\|=\text{spr}(A)=\max\{|\lambda|:\ \lambda\in\sigma(A)\}$.

From those two facts you easily deduce that $\|P\|=1$. Whenever $0\leq B\leq A$,  we have $\phi(B)\leq\phi(A)$ for any state $\phi$, so $\|B\|=\text{spr}(B)\leq\text{spr}(A)=\|A\|$.

As $\|1\|=1$, you are done.

Comment: Yes that's fine, fair enough!! :) I was expecting something like spectral radius anyway. The state space seems also not much more to involve. And if you're honest the operator algebraic proofs for the other threads also did somehow exploit topological properties from C*-algebra, at least the C*-identity.